Calling AIOKafkaConsumer via FastAPI raises "object should be created within an async function or provide loop directly" error
I have a FastAPI application that subscribes to Kafka topic in async mode. I have to create a unittest for my application.
My code:
def create_consumer() -> AIOKafkaConsumer:
    """Create AIOKafkaConsumer.

    Returns:
        AIOKafkaConsumer: The created AIOKafkaConsumer instance.
    """
    return AIOKafkaConsumer(
        settings.kafka_consumer_topic,
        bootstrap_servers=f"{settings.kafka_consumer_host}:{settings.kafka_consumer_port}"
    )

app = FastAPI()
consumer = create_consumer()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    """Startup event for FastAPI application."""

    log.info("Starting up...")
    await consumer.start()
    asyncio.create_task(consume())

async def consume(db: Session = next(get_db())):
    """Consume and print messages from Kafka."""
    while True:
        async for msg in consumer:
            ...

I am using FastAPI's TestClient:
import pytest

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import get_task_files
#from app.main import app

client = TestClient(app) # ERR: AIOKafkaConsumer The object should be created within an async function or provide loop directly.

However, I am getting an error in AIOKafkaConsumer instatiation:

The object should be created within an async function or provide loop directly.

How to properly test my application? It looks like I have to mock kafka-functionality.

Not that familiar with aiokafka, but based on the error you are getting, i.e., "The object should be created within an async function...", have you tried defining the create_consumer() function with async def instead of def?

Another way should most likely be to pass the event loop to AIOKafkaConsumer(loop=loop) at instatiation. You could get the event loop as demonstrated here, here and here, e.g., loop = asyncio.get_running_loop().

On a side note, I would suggest using a lifespan handler, as described in this answer, as startup event handler has been deprecated.

Based on the error shown in your question:

The object should be created within an async function or provide loop
directly.

you should try having the create_consumer() function, which is used to instantiate AIOKafkaConsumer, defined as async def instead of def. For instance:
async def create_consumer() -> AIOKafkaConsumer:
    return AIOKafkaConsumer(...

Alternatively, as mentioned in the error message above, you might try providing the event loop (of the main thread) directly to AIOKafkaConsumer object, while keeping the create_consumer() function defined with normal def—the event loop can be obtained, as demonstrated here, as well as here and here. For example:
def create_consumer() -> AIOKafkaConsumer:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return AIOKafkaConsumer(loop=loop, ...

On a side note, I would suggest using a lifespan handler to initialize global variables/objects and/or start services at application startup, as described in this answer, instead of the startup event handler that you are currently using, as it has been deprecated.
Also, there doesn't seem to be any reason for having the creation of AIOKafkaConsumer object inside a separate function rather than the lifespan handler itself. Hence, you could follow an apporach similar to the example below instead.
Example
It should be noted that in the example below, even though the event loop is provided to the AIOKafkaConsumer instance, it might not even be necessary to do that, as the object is created within an async def function that runs directly in the event loop.
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager


# Consume and print messages from Kafka
async def consume(consumer: AIOKafkaConsumer, db: Session = next(get_db())):
    while True:
        async for msg in consumer:
            ...


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() 
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer("my_topic", loop=loop, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
    await consumer.start()
    asyncio.create_task(consume(consumer))
    yield
    await consumer.stop()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

